# Regression with continous outcome and binary and count independent variables; looking for info/references

Tags: regression, references

Is there a name for a regression model (borrowing R formula syntax) $$y \sim b + N$$  where $y$ is a continous (possibly non-normal) outcome measure, $b$ is a binary variable (0, 1) and $N$ is a random variable of counts? Or can one simplify the problem by using a mixed model $y$ and $N$?

Comment: I don't think this has a special name. $b$ is just a factor, while I have seen something like N treated as a continuous covariate (sometimes log-transformed as often counts can have very skewed distributions and a few extreme covariate values might otherwise have excessive influence).

Comment: @Björn so I could formulate the problem as a mixed regression problem, then?

Comment: @Bjorn since counts can in many cases be 0, log counts are sometimes not a great idea.

Comment: @Glen_b Agree, if 0 can occur, then log is not suitable. I was thinking of something like cell counts in the blood, which for certain cell types would never be 0.

Comment: @Stijn I am not sure from what you have said why it would be a mixed model (i.e. why would there necessarily be a random effect anywhere, although that is of course possible).

Comment: If you told us your real problem (in applied language) then maybe we could help better.